# Using Sumproduct to calculate two tables using horizontal (table headers) and vertical references

Tags: excel

Hopefully the title makes some sense because I'm trying to wrap my head around the logic and I'm not quite sure how to phrase the question.I'll try to give a brief explanation of the end goal without over complicating it with unnecessary details.

I have a table of survey score averages for every month per person and a correlating table with the number of surveys each person received for each month. The logic is essentially multiple the score for each month by the number of surveys, combine them, divide by the total number of surveys within that time period to get their true average. Where things get a little complicated is that I have to include the ability to set a custom date range and return the value. So sometimes I might be looking at the average for Jan - Apr, other times I might just be looking at Feb-Mar etc.

[image: Here's a picture of a test workbook for reference.]

I think sumproduct is going to get what I need done but I'm running into issues trying to write it out. I've written it several different ways and none of them worked so here's one that best conveys what I'm trying to do,

[image: Here's an image showing the formula and what its targetting]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(F7:I7,L7:O7>=C2),--(F7:I7,L7:O7<=C3),--(E8:E12,K8:K12=B9),tbl_average[[Jan-20]:[Apr-20]],tbl_surveys[[Jan-20]:[Apr-20]])
```

I super appreciate any assistance I can get on this. I'm hoping the end result is not nearly as difficult as I'm making it out to be.

*Some additional information:*

I'm going to be using this same process to calculate multiple metrics across multiple worksheets.In the test example each of the tables will most likely be on different sheets. The dashboard with the calculated results will contain everyone's names and will be filtered and rearranged frequently, so I need to make sure we're always matching directly to their names and not just the relative rows. Basically, in my example I show that Agent 1 is always lined up on row 8 but that's not always going to be the case. Agent 1 could be in Row 8 on Sheet 1, Row 10 on Sheet 2, and Row 12 on Sheet 3 and I need all the correct values to multiply and sum against one another.

Comment: The main issue is that when one creates a table the headers all become text, they are no longer dates and therefore one must convert them back to dates in the formula to do the comparisons.

Comment: Hmm, what if I converted them to ranges and the columns remained the same across all the worksheets? The exported data is always going to be Agent Name on column A, months from columns B - M and I'm only looking at 2020.

Comment: As Long as the dates are true dates and not text it will make it easier.